# How to draw a line in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpneGL ES 2.0. I have read some articles about it and successes to draw triangle shape android program. Now I want to write simple app to draw a sin wave by this 10 points:

```
{-3.14, -0.00159265}, {-2.826, -0.31038}, {-2.512, -0.588816}, {-2.198, -0.809672}, {-1.884, -0.951351}, {-1.57, -1.}, {-1.256, -0.950859}, {-0.942, -0.808736}, {-0.628, -0.587528}, {-0.314, -0.308866}, {4.44089*10^-16, 4.44089*10^-16}, {0.314, 0.308866}, {0.628, 0.587528}, {0.942, 0.808736}, {1.256,0.950859}, {1.57, 1.}, {1.884, 0.951351}, {2.198, 0.809672}, {2.512,0.588816}, {2.826, 0.31038}, {3.14, 0.00159265}
```

I have created my main Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView surface;
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        surface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        surface.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        surface.setRenderer(new Renderer());

        setContentView(surface);
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        surface.onPause();      
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        surface.onResume();
    }
}
```

What should be Renderer and Line Classes in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Wow, where to begin? I guess you should probably start by following an OpenGL-ES 2.0 tutorial so that you can render a triangle or something basic. Then, you'll need to edit your x/y coordinate array to contain a Z coordinate (can be just 0). Then, wrap that array in a byte-buffer and draw using glDrawArrays (if not indexed) with GL_LINE_STRIP. Of course, you'll need to first setup your shaders & program, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried coding a simple triangle. I am a little bit familiar by shader and renderer but very very little and I do not know what is exacly syntax of a GL_LINE or GL_LINE_SRTIP and how to use it ib Rendered class. Is there any sample code available so I can check the codes. Thank a lot @GilMoshayof

Comment: GL_LINES forces you to specify 2 coordinates for every line draw (A to B, B to C, etc), while GL_LINE_STRIP assumes every following point connects to the last one (A to B to C, etc). For your purposes, LINE_STRIP is probably best, as you're aiming to draw 1 continuous line. Again though, there's some setup boiler-plate code you need to write first, so I would again suggest to follow a tutorial, get something working, then work from there.

Comment: Thanks. OpenGL is much easier than OpenGL ES. I didn't think it might be that hard

Comment: I already have written code to draw sin wave in OpenGL ES 1. I want this code in OpenGL ES 2.0. Any body can tell me how to convert them from ES 1.0 to ES 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to write two other classes:
First a shader Class:
public class `Shader`:

```
public class Shader {

    private final static String vertcode = "attribute vec4 a_pos;"+
            "void main(){"+
            "gl_Position = a_pos;" +
            "}";

    private final static String fragcode = "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 u_color;"+
            "void main(){"+
            "gl_FragColor = u_color;"+
            "}";

    private static int program;
    public static int positionhandle;
    public static int colorhandle;

    public static void makeprogram()
    {
        int vertexShader   = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertcode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragcode);

        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);

        positionhandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program,"a_pos");
        colorhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_color");


        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    }

    private static int loadShader(int type, String shadertext)
    {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shadertext);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }

}
```

And one other class name as `Renderer`. The `Renderer` class should contain your points cordinates.
Please not your points should be formatted as:

```
float vertices[] =  {
            0f,0f,0f,
            -3.14f, -0.00159265f, 0f,
            -2.826f, -0.31038f, 0f,
            -2.512f, -0.588816f, 0f,
            -2.198f, -0.809672f, 0f,
            -1.884f, -0.951351f, 0f,
            -1.57f, -1f, 0f,
            -1.256f, -0.950859f, 0f,
            -0.942f, -0.808736f, 0f,
            -0.628f, -0.587528f, 0f,
            -0.314f, -0.308866f, 0f,
            0f, 0f, 0f,
            0.314f, 0.308866f, 0f,
            0.628f, 0.587528f, 0f,
            0.942f, 0.808736f, 0f,
            1.256f, 0.950859f, 0f,
            1.57f, 1f, 0f,
            1.884f, 0.951351f, 0f,
            2.198f, 0.809672f, 0f,
            2.512f, 0.588816f, 0f,
            2.826f, 0.31038f, 0f,
            3.14f, 0.00159265f, 0f
            };
```